# sql - Retrieve elements of a certain group based on their max value without using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm still very new to SQL queries and am looking for a (supposedly) relatively simple solution to an issue I'm having:

Say I have two relational tables:

```
+--------+------------+           +--------+--------+-------------+-------+
| TypeNr | TypeName   |           | BeerNr | TypeNr | BeerName    |  ABV  |
+--------+------------+           +--------+--------+-------------+-------+
|   1    |  Lager     |           |   1    |   1    | Budweiser   |  5    |
|   2    |  IPA       |           |   2    |   2    | Goose IPA   |  5.9  |
|   3    |  Trappiste |           |   3    |   2    | Goose So-Lo |  3    |
+--------+------------+           |   4    |   2    | Lost Palate |  6.3  |
                                  |   5    |   3    | Rochefort 8 |  8    |
                                  |   6    |   3    | Rochefort 10|  10   |
                                  +--------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

I'd like to return TypeName, BeerName and ABV of the row having the highest ABV for each respective TypeNr.

Normally I'd just query something like this

```
SELECT table1.TypeName, MAX(table2.ABV)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.TypeNr = table2.TypeNr
GROUP BY table1.TypeName
```

Which would return:

```
Lager      5
IPA        6.3
Trappiste  10
```

What alternative can I use here so the query also returns the correct BeerName associated with the highest ABV?

```
Lager      Budweiser     5
IPA        Lost Palate   6.3
Trappiste  Rochefort 10  10
```

I feel I can no longer rely on GROUP BY when attempting this, because I'd be forced to also group by BeerName (since I'm also selecting it) which does not produce the result I want.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySQL 5.7.33